# add some dynamic attribute to restful routes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Is there any way to add dynamic attribute(s) to restful routes

```
resources :food_menus do
    resources :categories
end
```

This produces this and other crud routes:

```
food_menu_categories GET    /food_menus/:food_menu_id/categories(.:format)          categories#index
```

What I want to do:

```
ExtraDynamicAttribute_food_menu_categories GET    ExtraDynamicAttribute/food_menus/:food_menu_id/categories(.:format)          categories#index
```

ExtraDynamicAttribute to add before.

Any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scope

```
scope ':attribute' do
  resources :food_menus do
    resources :categories
  end
end
```

Comment: thx, I used it :) but did something wrong in it. One more thing @NARKOZ 

`
  resources :food_menus do
    scope ':attribute' do 
     resources :categories
    end
  end
`
is supposed to return 

/food_menus/:food_menu_id/:attribute/categories

But it is not working. Any Idea

Comment: you can't nest `scope` under `resources`